# Can't update selected files from the repository - no context menu for update

Tags: tortoisesvn

To avoide updating all items in repo Tortoise SVN help states that:

> Use **TortoiseSVN → Check for Modifications**. and click on **Check
>   repository** to see what has changed in the repository. Select the files
>   you want to update locally, then use the context menu to update just
>   those files.

But on my computer, when I right click inside the **Check for Modifications** dialog, on the missing folders that **Check Repository** button brought up, no **Update** command is available for me
Nor other SVN commands, only degenerated context menu apears

Comment: Not fully sure of what "on my computer" means exactly but the help document refers to the "Check for Modifications" dialogue—make sure that's where you're clicking on. Can you please edit the question and share a screenshot of the items the menu has?

Comment: Yes, I'm right clicking the missing folders that **Check Repository** button brought up. Thats inside the **Check for Modifications** dialog

Comment: I'm trying to repair/reinstall, but since I'm on a heavy security/privacy environment, I have to - still - wait ...